# Composer issue on updating Magento 2.2.2 to 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, composer

Today we tried to update Magento 2.2.2 to 2.2.3 just by requiring the new version with:

```
$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 --no-update
$ composer update
```

But after that running these commands, the following error is shown.

```
Package "magento/product-community-edition:2.2.3" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring. 
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                                                 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.2.2, required as 2.2.3) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Problem 2
        - Can only install one of: tubalmartin/cssmin[v4.1.1, v4.1.0].
        - Can only install one of: tubalmartin/cssmin[v4.1.1, v4.1.0].
        - Can only install one of: tubalmartin/cssmin[v4.1.0, v4.1.1].
        - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 requires tubalmartin/cssmin 4.1.1 -> satisfiable by tubalmartin/cssmin[v4.1.1].
        - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.3].
        - Installation request for tubalmartin/cssmin (locked at v4.1.0) -> satisfiable by tubalmartin/cssmin[v4.1.0].
```

I tried to solve this by requiring the latest version of tubalmartin/cssmin[v4.1.1], but that doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Somehow, the first commands just worked after trying again. I don't know why exactly, but maybe it had something to do with the composer.json and composer.lock. One of those two files was checked out to the original file from the Git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands do seem to be right. Closing post.

Comment: I would guess that this is due to composer.lock - as you have the `locked at` message